# Selenium Web Element:- How can I locate a Web element through text as displayed in Below code

Tags: web, element

This is the code please suggest how can locate Tester 123 through text using xpath.

Event Title:Tester 123

The best I can do is 
`td[contains(text(),'Tester 123')]`   but is not working.

How create Locator of Tester 123 through text.

[image: Create Locator of tester 123]

Comment: You should put your question and the code in your question instead of including a capture.

Comment: <td class="right aligned"><span style="font-weight:bold">Event Title:</span>Tester 123</td>                     This is the code please suggest how can locate Tester 123 through text using xpath.    The best I can do is //td[contains(text(),'Tester 123')]     but is not working.